# IOS 6 Xcode 4.5 MFMailComposer Crash

Tags: xcode, crash, ios6, mfmailcomposer

I have updated XCode to 4.5 and now the Email Function crashes, if I press the button to send an email.

What I am doing wrong?

I have implemented the MessageUI.framework in my header file

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import <MessageUI/MessageUI.h>

@interface ImpressumViewController : UIViewController <MFMailComposeViewControllerDelegate>
```

Here is my code for the button:

```
- (IBAction)kontakt:(id)sender {

    MFMailComposeViewController *mailcontroller = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    [mailcontroller setMailComposeDelegate:self];
    NSString *email =@"Youtube@gmail.com";
    NSArray *emailArray = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:email, nil];
    [mailcontroller setToRecipients:emailArray];
    [mailcontroller setSubject:@"Youtube Tutorials"];
    [self presentViewController:mailcontroller animated:YES completion:nil]; }

- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController *)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError *)error{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];



    }
```

Comment: Not sure, but try [self presentModalViewController:composer animated:YES completion:nil]; 
(Added the "Modal")

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer. But this don't work. I think Modal is old version

Comment: the exact same code works for me

Comment: I fixed my problem. It was a problem in my appdelegate with the background image of uitableview...

Comment: @user1355961 could you expound a little more on the solution you found? How would a background image affect sending an email?

Comment: Please expand on your solution, I am having this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You need write following code in this delegate method

```
- (void)mailComposeController:(MFMailComposeViewController*)controller didFinishWithResult:(MFMailComposeResult)result error:(NSError*)error 
{   switch (result)
    {
        case MFMailComposeResultCancelled:
            NSLog(@"Mail cancelled: you cancelled the operation and no email message was queued");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSaved:
            NSLog(@"Mail saved: you saved the email message in the Drafts folder");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultSent:
            NSLog(@"Mail send: the email message is queued in the outbox. It is ready to send the next time the user connects to email");
            break;
        case MFMailComposeResultFailed:
            NSLog(@"Mail failed: the email message was nog saved or queued, possibly due to an error");
            break;
        default:
            NSLog(@"Mail not sent");
            break;
    }

    //[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```